# How to increase the line height of RStudio editor?

Tags: rstudio

I wonder if there are any ways to increase the line height of the coding in RStudio.
[image]

Someone said that the following seems to work in the active.rstheme:

```
#rstudio_source_text_editor div { line-height: 1.3 !important; }
```

So I added it to the end of the active.rstheme but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: That command worked for me. Be sure to remove the "#" at the start of the line, and perhaps instead of "1.3" change it to "1.8" so the difference is clearer? Also, what rstheme are you using?

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thank you. I have removed the "#" but it still cannot work. Is it because of the rstheme I'm using? I'm using Material now.  What rstheme are you using?

Comment: I'm using a custom theme (atom dark); not sure what else to try - perhaps someone will come up with an answer or you could post your question to https://community.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `line-height` to the `ace_editor` selector in the .rstheme file worked for me.

```
.ace_editor, .rstudio-themes-flat.ace_editor_theme .profvis-flamegraph, 
.rstudio-themes-flat.ace_editor_theme, .rstudio-themes-flat .ace_editor_theme {
    background-color: #282c34;
    color: #abb2bf;
    line-height: 1.3 !important;
}
```

However, there may be a better way.